# Changing Numbers in file Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file which looks something like this

```
Value:
1
Value2:
2
Vlaue3:
4
Value4:
7
```

I want to be able to change the value under 'Value4', which in this case 7, to 8 while also leaving the rest of the file the same. How would you be able to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not programming service.

Comment: create a new file, edit and copy information, write to new file